# Dockerfile - Use extra packages from requirements.txt

Tags: docker, pip, debian

I'm using `Docker` and build a custom image. I base my image on a `Debian` distribution and add some packages with a `requirements.txt` file. When I build the `Docker` image, I can see packages installation in the log, but when I run it I can't use additionals packages from `requirements.txt` because the're not installed.

Is it link with `--break-system-packages` options ?

Because if i don't precise it, I have `error: externally-managed-environment`

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM debian:latest

# Setting code directory
WORKDIR /code

# Install pip
RUN set -xe \
    && apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip --break-system-packages

# Install requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --break-system-packages
```

**requirements.txt**

```
nano
psycopg2-binary
pandas
```

**Build image**

```
docker build --network=host -t "debian:latest" .
```

**Run it**

```
docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/sh debian
```

**Search packages (no results)**

```
dpkg --list | grep -i -e nano -e pandas -e psycopg
```

Comment: Any reason to not use the `python` base image?  It doesn't look like you're `COPY`ing your application code into the image or setting a default `CMD` to run it; are these parts missing?  Do you in fact mean the [`nano` PyPI package](https://pypi.org/project/nano/) in `requirements.txt`?  From the last line it seems like you're using the Python `pip` tool to install Python packages, but then expecting the Debian package-management system to know about them; this doesn't usually happen.

Comment: Why use `python` base image and not a `debian` one ? I don't have a `COPY` instruction you're right, my bad. Same with final `CMD`, what will it look like ?

Comment: Usually just `CMD ["./myapp.py"]` is enough.

Comment: You do `pip install` and then search installed packages with `dpkg --list`? That doesn't work: `pip` is independent of OS package managers. Use `pip list` or `pip freeze`.

Comment: Obvious reason, thanks. When I use `RUN apt-get install -y requirements.txt`, I can't see installed packages with `dpkg --list`, how to explain this ?

Comment: `apt`, `apt-get`, `aptitude`, `dselect` are not independent programs — they're different user interfaces to the same package database and the same mid-level package manager `dpkg` which in turn runs different low-level programs like `dpkg-deb`, `dpk-query` and many other. So anything installed with `apt` is visible with `dselect` or `dpkg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in the Dockerfile setup you show.  It seems like you're mixing operating-system packages (managed by `dpkg`) and Python packages (managed by `pip`) and this is causing some confusion.

Outside of Docker, I'd start by creating the `requirements.lock` file with the *exact* Python versions you need.  The [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/) describes some options around tooling.  For example purposes, I'll use a plain Python virtual environment:

```bash
python -m venv ./venv
. ./venv/bin/activate
pip install psycopg2-binary pandas
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

In your Docker setup, I'd suggest starting from a `python` base image.  This gives you more control over what exact version of Python is in use, and comes with some tools like `pip` preinstalled.  (You may have specific requirements in your local organization to build an image from a known starting point, in which case you should have guidance on how to get common language runtimes like this.)

Once you have installed the application's Python-level dependencies, don't forget to also copy in your code, and to set a default `CMD` for the container to run.

Put together, this might look like

```bash
FROM python:3.11

WORKDIR /code

# Copy the frozen requirements file in and install those packages.
# Use the "system" Python inside the isolated images.
# Do this separately to improve performance on rebuild.
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the application in.
COPY ./ ./

# Set the default command to run when you launch the container.
CMD ["./myapp.py"]
```

Your Python code should be able to `import` modules from the packages you installed using `pip install`.

The default `python` image happens to be Debian-based, but the Debian package management system (the `dpkg` tool and the higher-level APT wrapper) are separate from the Python packaging system.  Things you `pip install` won't be visible with `dpkg --list`.  If a Python library has a Debian package then in principle you can `apt-get install libpython-...`, but this isn't a typical Docker-based workflow.

Comment: Thanks for this clear and detailled answer.